# Rendering noscript version serverside without reuse markup warnings in React

Tags: reactjs

In my JS component I currently render the non-js version of the markup for compatibility with old browsers. Then Client-side this is re-rendered to the js-on markup.

This causes the error below where you can see the noscript version triggers this error.

> Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server:
>
> ```
> (client) <div class="shortlist ...
> (server) <noscript data-reacti ...
> ```

Is there a way to resolve this issue where the client gets the fastest experience while maintaining support for noscript browsers?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to replace `<noscript>` with `<div id="noscript" ref="noscript">` and in `componentDidMount` call `this.refs.noscript.style.display = 'none';`.

To hide the noscript div ASAP I've also added `<script>try{document.getElementById('noscript').style.display='none'}catch(e){}</script>` to the `index.html` just immediately after placeholder for serverside rendered markup.